# add image caption

Tags: attachments, captions

I would like to add caption to a image I just uploaded through a from. So I have the attachment id and the caption text in a variable.

I found wp_update_attachment_metadata in wordpress codex .. but how do I add caption through it?

Answer (score 1):

From quick look caption seems to be stored as excerpt (rather than part of data in meta array), so you should use [`wp_update_post()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_update_post) to add it.